# Multiple widgets to single AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-widget

I have some widgets for my app who do the same thing just a different in their layout causing a lot of duplicate code in multiple `AppWidgetProviders`, creating multiple of basically the same `appwidget-provider` xml files and filing up my manifest with all these different receivers.

Is there a way to setup widgets to use the same provider but with different layouts? As far as I understand each widget needs its own receiver in the manifest to show up

Answer (score -1):

Android supported loading different layout.set RemoteViews different is OK？